# Sockets - send and receive

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently writing a chat server in C++. When a user connects to it, I open a socket and I create two threads, one to receive and one to send data.

Now my question:
Do I have to check if the other thread is currently using the socket, or will the send/recv function just wait until the socket is ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending and receiving from TCP socket simultaneously should be entirely fine. (barring any possible OS bugs)

Answer (score 3):

Socket send and receive are independent.  You do not need to worry about interleaving them yourself.

Comment: They are independant on conceptual level, but there is common state on transport layer.

Comment: Surely, but that's abstracted away entirely by the Sockets API.  Heck, given the ACKs ever send or receive is both a send and receive.