# Java sockets: can you send from one thread and receive on another?

Tags: java, sockets

This is probably an extremely basic question but I'm having difficulty finding an answer.

Is it ok to have one thread writing to a Socket's output stream while another thread is reading from the Socket's input stream?

Edit: This is a client application that is speaking to an external server.  I am not trying to make the two threads talk to each other.  Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Java vs. C++, but still very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182806/sockets-send-and-receive .  Some additional discussion is also available at http://www.coderanch.com/t/207132/sockets/java/Multiple-threads-writing-reading-single .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean the threads are using the same socket to communicate with an external actor and not with each other, this is pretty common as you often don't want to block while waiting to read from the socket.

Thread1:

```
block on read
on recieve message - do something
```

Thread2:

```
do things
on something happening - write to socket
```

If instead you meant just having two threads communicate internally, you should look into non-socket alternatives.

Edit:  Also beware of potential concurrency issues, so check whether the streams you are using are thread safe.

Comment: Yes, I meant the first case: "the threads are using the same socket to communicate with an external actor and not with each other"

Comment: You say "beware of potential concurrency issues, so check whether the streams you are using are thread safe".  Can you explain?  Again, I'm talk to an external server.  If thread A is writing to the output stream and thread B is reading from the inputstream, is there a concurrency problem?

Comment: Not in the simple case.  You will have to handle what happens if one thread closes the connection and things of that nature though.

Answer (score 2):

People are confused by your question, and that's why half are saying "Yes, but that's not how two threads should communicate with each other", and the other interpret your question as being "I want one thread always writing to the socket, and another thread always reading from the socket so my program can send and receive simultaneously."  The later interpretation means those two threads are NOT using the socket to exchange information with each other, but another machine which makes this less icky.  The answer is YES.  Sockets are bidirectional so you can be sending and receiving data at the same time.  That doesn't mean you have to use two threads to do this.

Now, this is highly unusual.  Of all the time I've worked on socket protocols (POP, IMAP, HTTP, etc) I've never run into a situation where this was the case, or said another way, I've never seen a protocol that demands this occur.  At some point the protocol is synchronous and one of those ends has to wait before it sends more info or reads more info.  The only case I could think of is something like RTMP, Audio, or Video streaming.  However, I think most of those use some form of non-blocking IO so simulate simultaneous communication.

And that's the next thing you might want to consider.  When you are processing messages from the socket you might check the socket for data before blocking on it.  If it's there read it in, if you have data to write check and see if you can write without blocking, then write it.  Or use non-blocking IO sockets.  That way you only have a single thread reading/writing to a socket and sync'ing between reads/writes is a no brainer.  With threads you are going to have to use locking or semaphores or something to coordinate between them and that could lead to dead locks.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing that operation so long as you have good reason to communicate that way and not through other thread communication techniques.

It really isn't any different than thinking about the concept of two entirely different applications listening/writing to the same socket.

Answer (score 1):

In other words you want to use a socket to send information from one thread to another thread? Yes that's possible. I would strongly consider a different route (they can just pass each other a reference, so that would be better I would think), but it should work.

When learning how sockets work and the troubles involved, keeping them in the same application often simplifies things significantly, and that is something I strongly encourage.

But for production code, I'd recommend using references or a thread-safe queue or something similar.

Edit: in response to your comment and edits:

## *Yes.*

There are two ways you can do that: same thread, where you get input, then react to it, or use a separate thread so you can send information without necessarily receiving them. For simple programs the first is recommended because it's the most simple. But for anything beyond the simplest of protocols, you will want the second thread to desynchronize the input and output.

Comment: No sorry (I just edited by question).  I'm using two threads to talk to an external server, not trying to make two threads talk to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one thread reading while another is writing. AFAIK This is possibly the most common use case for blocking sockets.

It is possible to have multiple thread doing both but this is not simple and you rarely need more than one each.

---

You can have two thread communicating in the same process.  This is something I use often in unit tests where I have client and server components in the same process.

You can even use one thread to read write from both ends.
http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-puzzle-single-threaded-client.html

Alternatives might be to use a Piped Stream(s) which is slightly faster, or BlockingQueue(s) or Exchanger with ByteBuffers or a bunch or other options. ;)

Comment: No sorry (I just edited by question). I'm using two threads to talk to an external server, not trying to make two threads talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but what stream do you whant to use for creating a "buffer"? It must be something like BlockingQueue

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, sockets are bidirecional.
Just be careful when implementing your protocol. Make sure you synchronize the read and write calls, and frame your messages as well